# How to always call a method inside receive() even if nothing matches

Tags: scala, akka

I am fairly new to the Akka/Scala world. I am trying to figure out what is the best way of having something always executed when an actor is receiving a message even if there is no match for it. I know that `receive` is `PartialFunction` but I was wonder if there is a better way of doing this than:

```
def receive: Receive = {
  case string: String => { 
    functionIWantToCall()
    println(string)
  }
  case obj: MyClass => {
    functionIWantToCall()
    doSomethingElse()
  }
  case _ => functionIWantToCall()
}
```

I am pretty sure there is a better way in Scala for doing this instead of calling `functionIWantToCall()` inside each case. Can somebody suggest something :)?

Comment: Do you want a default case that's called only when no other case matches or do you want a function that's called always regardless of whether there was a match or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can wrap your Receive function in "higher-order" Receive function

```
  def withFunctionToCall(receive: => Receive): Receive = {
    // If underlying Receive is defined for message
    case x if receive.isDefinedAt(x) =>
      functionIWantToCall()
      receive(x)

    // Only if you want to catch all messages
    case _ => functionIWantToCall()
  }

  def receive: Receive = withFunctionToCall {
    case string: String => println(string)
    case obj: MyClass => doSomethingElse()
  }
```

Or you can read about Pipelines in Akka docs: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/contrib/receive-pipeline.html

I think it's exactly what you need for this type of problem

```
  val callBefore: Receive => Receive =
    inner ⇒ {
      case x ⇒ functionIWantToCall; inner(x)
    }

  val myReceive: Receive = {
    case string: String => println(string)
    case obj: MyClass => doSomethingElse()
  }

  def receive: Receive = callBefore(myReceive)
```

Comment: +1 to use Receive Pipeline, it's a really lightweight pattern and it was thought exactly for what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a stripped-down example that has nothing to do with Akka. These two match expressions are equivalent:

```
{
  case _: A =>
    foo()
    a()
  case _: B =>
    foo()
    b()
  case _ =>
    foo()
}

{
  case m =>
    foo()
    m match {
      case _: A =>
        a()
      case _: B =>
        b()
      case _ =>
    }
}
```